# Embed special tags inside XML between two tags

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a lot of wrongs embedded HTML tags inside XML.
like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <main>     
    <note>
        <category>computers</category>
        <id>1</id> 
            <price>47072.00</price>
        <description>
                <p>Warranty - 24<br />Product model code - N150
                Plus&nbsp;<br />            
            </description>      
   </note> 
</main>
```

I need to insert between  tags this code..to read the XML file using PHP
.

like this:

```
<description>
       <![CDATA[<html
        ...HTML CODE IS HERE

        ]]>
</description>
```

Comment: Use `Ctrl + K`, the 010101 button or indent 4 spaces for code (including HTML).

Comment: Is your question about which tool to use? XSLT won't work since the input isn't well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `file_get_contents()` to open xml file as array.